# Where does oracle store my object instances?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-type

I've created the following two object types :

```
create or replace type person_typ as object (
    person#                 varchar(10)
) not final;

create or replace type salesperson_typ under person_typ (
    salesperson#            varchar(10),
    sSurname                varchar(10),
    sForename               varchar(10),
    dateOfBirth             date
);

create table person_tab of person_typ (
    person# primary key
);
```

And I've inserted a row using :

```
insert into person_tab
values (salesperson_typ('p1','s1', 'Jones', 'John', sysdate));
```

Which I can retrieve using the following :

```
select 
    treat(value(s) as salesperson_typ).person# as person_number, 
    treat(value(s) as salesperson_typ).sSurname as sSurname
from 
    person_tab s
;
```

However, if I look at `person_tab` I only see the following :

```
SQL> select * from person_tab;

PERSON#
----------
p1
```

I'm curious, where does the `salesperson` specific data get stored? I was almost expecting to find a `salesperson` table, but I can't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Your object is stored invisibly in the same table.
You can check columns by querying USER_TAB_COLS:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'PERSON_TAB';
```

Then you can then use the column names* you just discovered in a query (except SYS_NC_ROWINFO$, that throws an error for me).

```
SELECT SYS_NC_OID$
      ,SYS_NC_TYPEID$ 
    --,SYS_NC_ROWINFO$
      ,PERSON#        
      ,SYS_NC00005$   
      ,SYS_NC00006$   
      ,SYS_NC00007$   
      ,SYS_NC00008$   
FROM PERSON_TAB;
```

**Note***

You should not use these column names in any application because they are internal and subject to change in future patches/releases.